# Trying to get opengl 2 shaders to work glxinfo says I have 4.20 installed

Tags: ati, kubuntu, opengl

I am trying to get opengl 2 shaders to work. I just installed kubuntu on my lenovo z575 laptop which sports a AMD A6-3420M APU, integrated 6520 gpu.

In kubuntu under desktop effects I have opengl 2 shaders enabled however for effects which require it, it gives me an error message x effect requires opengl 2

x= name of effect

glxinfo gave me this:
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6520G
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.00.11
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20

The complete log can be found here
http://pastebin.com/Z2GYVbqh

I have it set to:
compositing type: opengl
qt graphics system: native

because other options will disable the kde effects. I have also tried disabling vsync

On a secondary note does anyone know how to reopen that window that appears in the kubuntu desktop where one can store icons and close or expand the windows as they see necessary, I accidently closed it and I am lost on how to open it

Comment: bump still having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. AMD Drivers are junk, removing it & replacing w/ open source xserver-xorg-video-ati & xserver-xorg-video-radeon fixed the problem.